# What does it mean to solve recurrence relation?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

$$f(n)=3f(n-1)-f(n-2)-3f(n-3)+2f(n-4)-4$$
$$f(0)=0,f(1)=1,f(2)=2,f(3)=3$$
Given some recurrence relation with these starting conditions.

What does it mean to solve it? I don't need a solution for the exersice, just a clarification on the meaning of "solving it"?

**-Edit:**

After examining the answers, I get this solution:

$$f(n)-3f(n-1)+f(n-2)+3f(n-3)-2f(n-4)+4=0$$

In order to a general solution I "discarded" the '4' and wrote it like this, using characteristic polynomial: $$x^{4}-3x^{3}+x^{2}+3x-2=0$$

The solutions for this equations are: **2,1,-1**

Then I wrote it like this: $a_{n}=a_{1}2^{n}+a_{2}1^{n}+a_{3}(-1)^{n}-4$

**Is that the right direction for solving this equation?** 
afterwards I think I suppose to solve 4 equations using the 4 starting conditions at the beginning.

Comment: Here they mean a closed form solution.  As this is linear, there is one...though there's no guarantee that it is pleasant.  I'd start with the homogeneous form, $a_n=3a_{n-1}-a_{n-2}-3a_{n-3}+2a_{n-4}$.

Comment: The idea is to find an expression for $f(n)$ in terms of $n$

Comment: $x^4-3x^3+x^2+3x-2=0$ is a fourth degree equation, so it has four roots. They are $2,1,1,-1$. Yes, the repeated root is important.

Answer (score 1):

Solving the recurrence means expressing $f(n)$ in terms of $n$ and no other instance of $f$. You give an explicit expression of $f$ instead of an implicit one.

E.g.

$$f(n)=f(n-1)+1,\\f(0)=0$$ is a recurrence which is solved by

$$f(n)=n.$$

---

Likewise, solving the quadratic equation

$$x^2+2x+1=0$$ is making $x$ explicit,

$$x=-1.$$